# Arc paths with rounded corners

Tags: svg

I'd like to draw an arc segment:

[image: Rounded arc segment]

(90° here, but I want different arcs, for something like [Fan Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JU9E.jpg))

I can draw the arc (the yellow segment) fine with an `a/A` path segment, however, as soon as I want to *round* the corners, the arc (blue segment) *isn't* actually a full (circular) arc any longer, but is "flattened". Is there still any way to draw this part of the path with the `a/A` primitives, or should I just draw them in a *separate* path that allows me to set the center point correctly?

Comment: You can draw a square with a very whide yellow stroke (10 units) filled blue for example `d="M0,-5V100H105V-5Z"` Then you can use clipPath to clip the square with a path like `d="M-5,5Q0,0 5,0A95 95 0 0 1 100 95Q100,100 95,105H-5Z"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be explained with a bit of trigonometry. Consider the following three paths:

[image]

The first has the path definition (center of the arc at `0, 100`).

```
d="M 0,100 H 80 A 80,80 0 0 0 0,20 z"
```

In the second one, the corners have been rounded with a radius of 15. To keep the connection of the small corner arcs with the larger arc smooth, the larger radius is reduced from 80 to 65. As you can see, the arc sits wide outside its original position.

```
d="M 0,100 H 65 A 15,15 0 0 0 80,85 65,65 0 0 0 15,20 15,15 0 0 0 0,35 Z"
```

In the third one, the connection is ignored and the radius kept at 80. Still, the position of the arc is too wide.

```
d="M 0,100 H 65 A 15,15 0 0 0 80,85 80,80 0 0 0 15,20 15,15 0 0 0 0,35 Z"
```

That is because the small corner arc is too far from the center of the large arc. For a visual construction, you would draw a circle with radius 15 inside the pie, and move it towards the corner until it meets both the straight line and the arc in a tangent. See the green circle:

[image]

It is meeting the arc to the right of the upper corner, and a bit lower. How much lower, you have to compute.

Suppose you want to round the corner with a radius of `d=15`. Then, the center of the circle sits at the intersection of the vertical line at `x = d = 15` and the reduced arc with `r₂ = r₁ - d = 65`.

The angle α of a line from the inner corner to that point computes to

```
α = arcsin(d / r₂) = arcsin(15 / 65) = 13.342364°
```

The end point of the large arc then is at

```
x = cx + r₁ × sin(α) = 80 × sin(13.342364°) = 18.4615
y = cy - r₁ × cos(α) = 100 - 80 × cos(13.342364°) = 22.1593
```

The point where the rounded corner begins is at

```
x = cx = 0
y = cy - r₂ × cos(α) = 100 - 65 × cos(13.342364°) = 36.7544
```

After doing the same computation for the lower right corner, the final path computes to

```
d="M 0,100 H 63.25 A 15,15 0 0 0 77.85,81.54 80,80 0 0 0 18.46,22.15 15,15 0 0 0 0,36.75 Z"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! So, my fault is probably that I "just" moved the end of the corner point in by the distance of the rounded corner, and didn't actually use the "inner" (blue) circle to calculate the end-point correctly.. thank you very much for explaining this, I'll try to adjust my code, but this looks very promising!